# How to apply css to highlighted text in angular?

Tags: angular

I have 3 labels and I am allowing the user to select the text and store it. I want to highlight the selected text.

I am calling one function to store each highlighted text and storing it in an array based on index passed in function.

In html

```
<p (mouseup)="showSelectedText(0)">
    Select the text to highlight 1
</p>

<p (mouseup)="showSelectedText(1)">
    Select the text to highlight 2
</p>

<p (mouseup)="showSelectedText(2)">
    Select the text to highlight 3
</p>
```

TS

> ```
>  showSelectedText(id) {
>   var text = "";
>   if (window.getSelection) {
>      text = window.getSelection().toString();
>   }
>   this.highlightText[id] = text;
>   console.log(this.highlightText);   
> }
> ```

I am able to store the highlighted text and store based on respective index. But I am not able to add css for selected text.

If user selects first word from each paragrach I want to highlight it with some color.
i.e If `Select` word is highlighted in each paragraph then it should be differentiated with some color.
How can I do that?

Is there any way i can achieve this with `ngClass` / `ngStyle` or any other way?

> [Stackblitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-style-string-sanitizer-dsry6v?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: Even I have the same issue..How can I add styling  to substring?  Not to entire div

Answer (score 0):

you have to add ngclass to you elements:

```
<p (mouseup)="showSelectedText(0)" [ngClass]="{'myhighlightclass': 
 selectedElement === 0}">
Select the text to highlight 1
</p>

<p (mouseup)="showSelectedText(1)"  [ngClass]="{'myhighlightclass': 
 selectedElement === 1}">
  Select the text to highlight 2
 </p>

 <p (mouseup)="showSelectedText(2)"  [ngClass]="{'myhighlightclass': 
  selectedElement === 2}">
Select the text to highlight 3
 </p>
```

2- add this selectedelementAttribute tou you model `.ts` file

3- add a css clss :

```
myhighlightclass: {
 backgould-color:yellow;
}
```

3 change the selected element hen you make an action for example:

```
showSelectedText(id) {
this.selectedElement = id
 var text = "";
 if (window.getSelection) {
 text = window.getSelection().toString();
 }
 this.highlightText[id] = text;
  console.log(this.highlightText);   
  }
```

Comment: You misunderstood my question I guess. If user selects first word in first sentence I want to add background color to only that word.

Comment: thaks to the condition in the ngclass only one element will recieve the class

Comment: I Know dude. I want to style only one word in the first sentence. For example if user selects `Select` in first sentence. Only `Select` should be highlighted not `Select the text to highlight 1`

Comment: see this link: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_text_selection

Comment: Yes they are just adding the style for highlighted text. I need to check the conidition if it matches then need to apply style to only that paricular substring not to entire block

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224978/discussion-between-iamgrooot-and-habib-chabbi).